# Using Perl to read fixed-length records from a file

Tags: arrays, perl, byte

Is there a way for me to get bytes from a file and store it in a Perl array?

For example, if my file has 100 bytes, I want to be able to create an array in which each element holds 10 bytes.

I know how to create arrays and store lines but I'm not sure on how to get only bytes.

Answer (score 7):

The *input record separator* `$/` is normally set to a string (usually newline `"\n"`) that indicates the end of each record in the file.

However, it can also be set (temporarily) to a *reference to* an integer that specifies the size of fixed-length records.

You are also likely to want to read the file in raw (binary) mode, so your code would look something like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my @data = do {
  open my $fh, '<:raw', 'myfile';
  local $/ = \10;
  <$fh>;
};
```

Note that, if it is more convenient, the length can be a string

```
local $/ = \'10';
```

or a variable that contains the integer or string

```
my $record_size = 10;
local $/ = \$record_size;
```